# Spring MVC application without web.xml deployed in tomcat gives 404 Error

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat7

I have developed an application in Spring MVC and it is working fine when I directly run it from eclipse by Run as -> Run On Server.

But now I want to deploy the war to Tomcat folder and run it from there. I have done changes for that and war is getting deployed correctly to the desired tomcat folder but when I start tomcat server and access app url in browser it is giving me 404 error. Server is starting without any exceptions.

Below is the project structure and files :

**Project Structure ->**

[image: Project Structure]

**pom.xml ->**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DesertLamp</groupId>
  <artifactId>DesertLamp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <outputDirectory>C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.76\webapps</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**DesertLampWebApplicationConfig.java ->**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "co.in.desertlamp")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "co.in.desertlamp")
@Import(value = { DesertLampSecurityConfiguration.class })
public class DesertLampWebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**DesertLampInitializer.java**

```java
public class DesertLampInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DesertLampWebApplicationConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**DesertLampApplicationConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "co.in.desertlamp")
@ComponentScan({ "co.in.desertlamp" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/co/in/desertlamp/resources/desertlamp.properties" })
public class DesertLampApplicationConfig {

    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "co.in.desertlamp" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(DataSourceCondition.class)
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        //Put Logger here
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/co/in/desertlamp/scripts/loadUserAndRoleData.sql"));
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL));
        return hibernateProperties;        
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "co.in.desertlamp" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**-> server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**-> Web Content Structure**

[image]

**-> DefaultController.java**

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("common/pgDefault");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error",required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid Email OR Password");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("message", "You are successfully logged out");
        }

        model.setViewName("common/pgLogin");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage(ModelMap model){
        String userEmailID = DesertLampUtils.getPrincipal();
        User user = userService.findByEmail(userEmailID);
        String userFirstName = user.getFirstName();
        model.addAttribute("userFirstName",userFirstName);
        return "common/pgWelcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accessDeniedPage(Principal principal) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        String currentUser = DesertLampUtils.getPrincipal();
        model.addObject("currentUser", currentUser);
        model.setViewName("common/pgAccessDenied");
        return model;
    }

}
```

The url I am requesting is http://localhost:8080/DesertLamp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which URL you are requesting in the browser?

Comment: please show the URL you request.

Comment: @javaguy - The url I am requesting is http://localhost:8080/DesertLamp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/.

Comment: @JunbangHuang - The url I am requesting is localhost:8080/DesertLamp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @javaguy can I see your server setting in server.xml?

Comment: @JunbangHuang - I have attached server.xml

Comment: @SubodhRanadive I am wondering why the URL is http://localhost:8080/DesertLamp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ instead of http://localhost:8080/DesertLamp/.

Comment: @JunbangHuang - When I did maven 'clean install' from eclipse the war generated was DesertLamp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war . I even tried with localhost:8080/DesertLamp/ but still I am getting 404.

Comment: @SubodhRanadive can u show me the webcontent folder？

Comment: @JunbangHuang - I have attached webcontent folder snapshot. Also I have attached my controller class.

Comment: @SubodhRanadive everything looks good. I suspect that would be your tomcat's problem. You can try to deploy a test project to see whether your tomcat works. If you don't mind, you can send me your code so that I can test it on my server.

Comment: @JunbangHuang - Sure, Where should I share the code?

Comment: @SubodhRanadive you can send it to my email: wongzeonbong@gmail.com

Comment: @JunbangHuang - I have emailed you the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing the code, I noticed that the reason why you are getting 404 is because your application doesn't start correctly due to the reason that the sql and properties file are not found.

In your code, the sql and properties files are placed with the java code. When maven compiles the java code, the sql and properties files are ignored because they are not java file. Therefore, they didn’t make their way to the class folder, and as a result. You are not able to access them during runtime.

In maven, there are three main folders. src/main/java. src/main/resources, src/test/java. java code should go to the first one, test should go to the last one and resources should go to the second one. Therefore, your properties, sql files should be placed in the src/main/resource folder. During compiling, everything in the src/main/resource folder will be put into WEB-INF/classes/ folder. So, you will be accessing them under the path: classpath: xxxx.properties.